# Without running std::min & std::max algorithm header file

Tags: c++

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdRQe.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout << max(1, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

(Sorry for my bad English)
Hi! I can't understand how it works.
I'm not using algorithm header but it work. I test it on Visual Studio 2019, xcode and ideone.com. Please check the screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: A header like `iostream` (or any other header) can include further other headers, but there is no guarantee about which headers `iostream` might include or if this will change in future or for all std libs. So you should always include the header corresponding to the functions and classes you are about to use in the file directly.

Comment: Actually, it does not run on Visual Studio 2019 implementation. It can compile on GCC implementation as the `<iostream>` header there implicitly or explicitly includes the `<algorithm>` header somewhere. A rule of thumb is: if you need a header, include it, do not rely on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Such things happen when a header internally includes another header whose function you're using.

In this case maybe the compilers you're using have implemented `<iostream>` in a way that it is including `<algorithm>`.

If you want your code to be portable, then you should never rely on how your compiler implements it. (You should rely on how the standard guarantees it.)

You should include each and every header file that is necessary.

Comment: But one problem in this context, I've ran the same code given by the asker, that fails on VSCode. It throws **namespace std has no member 'max'**. I'm not sure why results are unexpected for both of us.

Comment: @LinuXMan I think you're getting the correct result. The code doesn't work on Visual Studio 2019 until and unless one hasn't changed the default compiler! Though it works on `g++` and `clang`.

Comment: Oh wow, that's when I tried both `using namespace std;` and without implementing namespace, `std::max()`, both threw the same results.

Comment: @LinuXMan Actually VS Code and VS are two different things. I hope you meant the same or was using `vc++` to build your code in VS Code. BTW it doesn't compiles for sure on MSVC compiler.